# Compute symmetric matrix of a large file with awk

Tags: matrix, awk, symmetric

I have an OD matrix (origin-destination matrix) written in list form, like this `inputfile.csv`:

```
"origin_id","destination_id","trips"
"0","0","20"
"0","1","12"
"0","2","8"
"1","0","23"
"1","1","50"
"1","2","6"
"2","1","9"
"2","2","33"
```

Which reads as:

- There was 20 trips from origin_id=0 to destination_id=0,
- There was 12 trips from origin_id=0 to destination_id=1,
- And so on.

All the origin-destination pairs that have 0 trips, are not present in the input file (the elements of the matrix with zeros).

I need to compute the symmetric matrix as `S=(OD+DO)/2`, but the main problem is that the `inputfile.csv` is 30GB in size. I thought that a tool like **awk** could be a good solution, but I don't know how to proceed. I think that the pseudo algorithm should be something like this:

1. Read line, keep `origin1,destination2` and `trips12` (where `origin1,destination2` can be any `origin_id` or `desitnation_id`).

   - If `destination2,origin1` is present in the file, keep `trips21` and write:
     `origin1,destination2 --> (trips12+trips21)/2`
   - Else write: `origin1,destination1: (trips12)/2`

- Same for every pair (origin-destination).

I think that **awk** can be great for this task, but I am open to use any suggested tool (python, perl, octave, etc...)

```
awk -F"\"" '{a[$2$4]==$6;if $4$2 ...}' inputfile.csv
```

No clue how to do it...

Desired output:

```
"origin_id","destination_id","trips"
"0","0","20"  
"0","1","17.5"
"0","2","4"
"1","1","50"
"1","2","7.5"
"2","2","33"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much RAM do you have? Would this approach work?

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}

NR == 1 {
    print
}

{
    gsub("\"", "", $3)
    a[$1 FS $2] = $3
    b[$2 FS $1] = $3
}

END {
    for (i in a) {
        if (i in b) {
            print i, "\"" (a[i] + b[i]) / 2 "\""
        }
    }
}' inputfile.csv
"origin_id","destination_id","trips"
"0","2","12.5"
"0","1","8.5"
"1","1","22"
"0","0","12"
"1","0","8.5"
"2","0","12.5"
```

Comment: Thank for your answer! I have 32GB of RAM, for the moment I am testing your script in smaller-toy-matrixs. Your answer works when all the matrix elements are non-zero, if there are missing elements it does skip them. I modified a little bit your script

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the answer of @jared_mamrot to my needs, I am using this (note the `else`):

```
awk BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}

NR==1 { 
print; next 
}

{
    gsub("\"", "", $3)
    a[$1 FS $2] = $3
    b[$2 FS $1] = $3
}

END {
    for (i in a) {
        if (i in b) {
            print i, "\"" (a[i] + b[i]) / 2 "\""
        } 
        else {
            print i, "\"" (a[i]) / 2 "\""
        }
    }
}' inputfile.csv
```